# How to make a counter and reset if condition doesn't match

Tags: java

I'm writing a code where I have to compare data between excel rows, if I find a match I want to increment my `finalIndex` by 1 and once the matches are found I need to merge the cells. Here I'm unable to understand how to maintain the track of the starting row number.

Below is my code. How can I do this?

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fin);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
int row = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
String currentLawName, currentCountry, currentAssociate, previousLawName, previousCountry, previousAssociate;
String currentPages, previousPages;
int startIndex = 0, finalIndex = 0, tempNum = 0;
System.out.println(row);
for (int i = 2; i < row; i++) {
    currentAssociate = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).toString();
    currentLawName = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3).toString();
    currentCountry = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(4).toString();
    currentPages = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(5).toString();

    previousAssociate = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(1).toString();
    previousLawName = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(3).toString();
    previousCountry = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(4).toString();
    previousPages = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(5).toString();

    if (currentAssociate.equals(previousAssociate) && currentCountry.equals(previousCountry)
        && currentLawName.equals(previousLawName) && currentPages.equals(previousPages)) {
        finalIndex += 1;
    } else {
        finalIndex = 0;
    }

}
System.out.println(finalIndex + "\t" + tempNum);
```

Comment: So you're trying to compare 2 subsequent excel rows, and if they're equal, you want to increment a count. If they're not equal, and count is greater than zero, you want to merge them? Wouldn't the starting row number be `i - finalIndex`?

Comment: Hi @SaviourSelf, I started the rows from second itself, and I took finalIndex just to count rows.

Comment: Yes,  but your question is `how to maintain the track of the starting row number.` If you increment `finalIndex` for every duplicate found (say you found 2), then the starting row number would be `i - finalIndex` or your current row - 2.